# Combine worksheets and add column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains multiple tabs that identify different sources of data.  I need to combine all the worksheets into one and add a column with the worksheet name as part of the new combined sheet.

I found the following code and if I cut/paste into my worksheet it works like a charm BUT I have several of these workbooks and I have to be able to recreate this process monthly.

My research indicates that I should create a com add in or recallable macro to do this but each time I have tried, the process fails.  I would very much appreciate if somone could point me with the steps to do this in Excel (2013) and advise me if my code will work.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim Location As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsNew = Sheets("Combined")
    On Error GoTo 0
        'if sheet does not already exist, create it
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(before:=Sheets(1)) ' add a sheet in first place
        wsNew.Name = "Combined"
    End If

    'copy headings and paste to new sheet starting in B1
    With Sheets(2)
        Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy wsNew.Range("B1") 
    End With

    ' work through sheets
    For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
        'save sheet name/location to string
        Location = Sheets(J).Name

        'set range to be copied
        With Sheets(J).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set rngCopy = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With

        'set range to paste to, beginning with column B
        Set rngPaste = wsNew.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)

        'copy range and paste to column *B* of combined sheet
        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste

        'enter the location name in column A for all copied entries
        Range(rngPaste, rngPaste.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1) = Location

    Next J
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this code into your Personal Macro Workbook, and modify it so it acts on the ActiveWorkbook. That way, when you run it, it will operate on whichever workbook is selected in Excel.

Also worth qualifying all your sheet references with a workbook object reference.  When you use (e.g.):

```
Sheets("Combined")
```

then by default it will refer to the `ActiveWorkbook`.  Usually this is what you want (though it may not be), but working this way can cause problems if (for example) you open/activate a different workbook in your code, and that other workbook is now the target of your `Sheets(....)` reference.  You resolve this by always being explicit about which workbook you're referring to: for example -

```
ThisworkBook.Sheets()             'the workbook containing the running code
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets()           'the selected workbook
Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets()   'named workbook
wb.Sheets()                       'use a variable set to a workbook object
```

So, modifying your existing code:

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim J As Integer, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim Location As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsNew = wb.Sheets("Combined")
    On Error GoTo 0
        'if sheet does not already exist, create it
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then
        Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets.Add(before:=wb.Sheets(1)) ' add a sheet in first place
        wsNew.Name = "Combined"
    End If

    'copy headings and paste to new sheet starting in B1
    With wb.Sheets(2)
        .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count) _
                   .End(xlToLeft)).Copy wsNew.Range("B1") 
    End With

    ' work through sheets
    For J = 2 To wb.Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
        'save sheet name/location to string
        Location = wb.Sheets(J).Name

        'set range to be copied
        With wb.Sheets(J).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set rngCopy = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With

        'set range to paste to, beginning with column B
        Set rngPaste = wsNew.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)

        'copy range and paste to column *B* of combined sheet
        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste

        'enter the location name in column A for all copied entries
        wsNew.Range(rngPaste, rngPaste.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1) = Location

    Next J

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your comments.  Since I am very new to this, can you advise what you mean by "qualifying all your sheet references with a workbook object reference".

Comment: Thanks Tim! That worked like a charm!  I will study this so I can do more of these!