# Excel - Merge worksheets with different structure

Tags: excel, merge, worksheet, vba

I have a Excel workbook with over 100 worksheets all of which have a different structure (some columns are in all of those worksheets, but some are not). Is there an easy way to merge the worksheets by the columns they have in common?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See if one of these links will help you:  1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480227/how-to-consolidate-data-from-multiple-excel-columns-all-into-one-column  2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648906/combine-worksheets-and-add-column-in-excel  3. https://danwagner.co/how-to-combine-data-with-different-columns-on-multiple-sheets-into-a-single-sheet/

Comment: Maybe a low tech approach: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Open the VBA Editor window
- Click “Tools” from the File menu
- Select “References” from within the Tools menu
- Scroll down until you find “Microsoft Scripting Runtime”
- Check the box next to the “Microsoft Scripting Runtime”
- Click OK

Then paste this into an Excel vba module:

```
    Option Explicit
    Public Sub CombineSheetsWithDifferentHeaders()

        Dim wksDst As Worksheet, wksSrc As Worksheet
        Dim lngIdx As Long, lngLastSrcColNum As Long, _
            lngFinalHeadersCounter As Long, lngFinalHeadersSize As Long, _
            lngLastSrcRowNum As Long, lngLastDstRowNum As Long
        Dim strColHeader As String
        Dim varColHeader As Variant
        Dim rngDst As Range, rngSrc As Range
        Dim dicFinalHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicFinalHeaders = New Scripting.Dictionary

        'Set references up-front
        dicFinalHeaders.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        lngFinalHeadersCounter = 1
        lngFinalHeadersSize = dicFinalHeaders.Count
        Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Start Phase 1: Prepare Final Headers and Destination worksheet'
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'First, we loop through all of the data worksheets,
        'building our Final Headers dictionary
        For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            'Make sure we skip the Destination worksheet!
            If wksSrc.Name <> wksDst.Name Then

                With wksSrc

                    'Loop through all of the headers on this sheet,
                    'adding them to the Final Headers dictionary
                    lngLastSrcColNum = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)
                    For lngIdx = 1 To lngLastSrcColNum

                        'If this column header does NOT already exist in the Final
                        'Headers dictionary, add it and increment the column number
                        strColHeader = Trim(CStr(.Cells(1, lngIdx)))
                        If Not dicFinalHeaders.Exists(strColHeader) Then
                            dicFinalHeaders.Add Key:=strColHeader, _
                                                Item:=lngFinalHeadersCounter
                            lngFinalHeadersCounter = lngFinalHeadersCounter + 1
                        End If

                    Next lngIdx

                End With

            End If

        Next wksSrc

        'Wahoo! The Final Headers dictionary now contains every column
        'header name from the worksheets. Let's write these values into
        'the Destination worksheet and finish Phase 1
        For Each varColHeader In dicFinalHeaders.Keys
            wksDst.Cells(1, dicFinalHeaders(varColHeader)) = CStr(varColHeader)
        Next varColHeader

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'End Phase 1: Final Headers are ready to rock!'
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Start Phase 2: write the data from each worksheet to the Destination!'
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'We begin just like Phase 1 -- by looping through each sheet
        For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            'Once again, make sure we skip the Destination worksheet!
            If wksSrc.Name <> wksDst.Name Then

                With wksSrc

                    'Identify the last row and column on this sheet
                    'so we know when to stop looping through the data
                    lngLastSrcRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
                    lngLastSrcColNum = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)

                    'Identify the last row of the Destination sheet
                    'so we know where to (eventually) paste the data
                    lngLastDstRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

                    'Loop through the headers on this sheet, looking up
                    'the appropriate Destination column from the Final
                    'Headers dictionary and creating ranges on the fly
                    For lngIdx = 1 To lngLastSrcColNum
                        strColHeader = Trim(CStr(.Cells(1, lngIdx)))

                        'Set the Destination target range using the
                        'looked up value from the Final Headers dictionary
                        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngLastDstRowNum + 1, _
                                                  dicFinalHeaders(strColHeader))

                        'Set the source target range using the current
                        'column number and the last-occupied row
                        Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, lngIdx), _
                                            .Cells(lngLastSrcRowNum, lngIdx))

                        'Copy the data from this sheet to the destination!
                        rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst

                    Next lngIdx

                End With

            End If

        Next wksSrc

        'Yay! Let the user know that the data has been combined
        MsgBox "Data combined!"

    End Sub

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
    'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
    'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
    Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
        Dim lng As Long
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
            With Sheet
                lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Row
            End With
        Else
            lng = 1
        End If
        LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
    'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
    'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
    Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
        Dim lng As Long
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
            With Sheet
                lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Column
            End With
        Else
            lng = 1
        End If
        LastOccupiedColNum = lng
    End Function
```

Then run the macro.
Original source adapted from: https://danwagner.co/how-to-combine-data-with-different-columns-on-multiple-sheets-into-a-single-sheet/